# Why is Gmail sending mail to wrong location (not respecting mx record)?

Tags: mx-record, gmail

I have a domain (`alarinsights.com`) setup with email hosted by Office365.  Everything works fine, except when I try to send myself email from gmail, I get a message bounced back saying no such user.  The server that sent that message back, however, is not Office365 - it's the server where my A record is pointing, not the MX record.

There's no reason the A and MX records need to point to the same server, right?  Why would gmail be picking up that address?

If it's important, the "bad" server was hosting my email at one point (a couple weeks ago).  Is Gmail caching it somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the TTL for your `MX`? More important: what was it before?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Gmail were caching DNS longer than they should. Gmail unfortunately does a whole lot of stuff wrong (e.g. not reading SPF records correctly). Your DNS records do look correct, so there's little else you can do but wait. Unless, of course, you have some super secret way to contact Gmail that the rest of us don't.

Comment: TTL set to an hour.  It might have been longer before, but I can't imagine it was more than a day or two.  Definitely shorter than it's been.  Guess I'll keep waiting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally (2 years later) found the answer.  The problem was the gmail account was setup to send through SMTP using the alarinsights.com STMP server.

So when the email got there, it saw the local email address and passed it along internally (only to find there was no such address).  I changed the email routing setting in cpanel to 'backup mail exchanger' (though 'remote mail exchanger' works too - just not 'local mail exchanger').